# How to use ListFragment in Android Swipe Tabs?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have used this code before for a swipe tab view with two layouts and it works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_OBJECT, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab_new;
        break;
        case 1:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab_summary;
        break;

        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

For that, I simply created 2 xml files and initialized them when the tabs are positioned correctly; however, now I want to have 2 tabs but the second one has to be a list. I'm not sure how to do that. I tried extending listFragment, but it crashed with resource not found. I've been stuck for a long time now, someone please help? I googled a lot and looked at all the examples but none of them show me how to make a list within a tab and how to call that.

Here's what I have right now
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
SimpleListFragment x = new SimpleListFragment();
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_OBJECT, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

        int tabLayout = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        tabLayout = R.layout.tab_home;
        break;
        case 1:
            SimpleListFragment simpleListFragment = new SimpleListFragment();

        break;

        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest you do no use the inner dummy `Fragment` class Eclipse creates... modify the pager to load your own fragments and implement your `ListView` there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you clarify a little more? I just started programming for android do I'm still basically a noob.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no short explanation for that. If you admit that you are a noob in Android development you should have a read about how to use and implement Fragments.Tabs are basically only a fancy way to replace Fragmentd in the main viewport (Pager). The PagerAdapter is responsible to manage which those Fragments are (just like an adapter of a ListView).

Comment: Therefore the `getItem()` method should return your own Fragments depending on the position and not generically create a dummy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ATM you are creating your ListFragment in the DummySectionFragment. Thats not right.

Here is one way of doing it. Not the best but one thats good to understand.

Create the fragments in the main activity and pass them to the adapter. The DummyListFragment is a new class derived from ListFragment. Important here is that the XML layout that it uses contains a ListView that has the id @android:id/list. (so the fragment is able to understand which listview it has to / can use.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

List<Fragment> mFragments;


@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
 mFragments.add(new DummySectionFragment();
 mFragments.add(new DummyListFragment();

  mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager(), mFragments);
```

> ...

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<Fragment> fragmentList;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentList = fragments;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = fragmentList.get(position);        
        return fragment;
    }
```

> . .

```
public static class DummyListFragment extends ListFragment {

public DummyListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: It's giving me an error when I try to add the DummyListFragment to the Fragment arraylist?

Comment: Strange. Did you inherit from  android.support.v4.app in all cases?

Comment: Nice, thanks, that fixed it. Is there any way to contact you? I'm getting a nullpointer in the main which I don't know why and don't want to spam another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's have a look.

1. Completely remove the `DummySectionFragment` class
2. Create two separate Fragments. One for your your `ListView` & the other one. Make sure you get them working. The code which was generated by Eclipse uses the Fragment class from the [**support library**](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) and therefore your Fragments have to extends the `Fragment` (or `ListFragment`) class from `android.support.v4.app` and **not** from `android.app`. Make sure you import the correct one.
3. Change your implementation of the `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

   ```
   public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
   {
       public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
       {
           super(fm);
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int pos)
       {
           // return instances of your custom fragments
           // tab 0: list
           // tab 1: other
           // (for more than 2 tabs use a switch statement instead)
           return (position == 0) ? new MyListFragment() : new MyOtherFragment();
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount()
       {
           // Defines the number of tabs shown and positions that getItem() should handel
           return 2;
       }

       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
       {
           // define the titles for your tabs in the strings.xml resource
           switch (position)
           {
               case 0: return getString(R.string.tab_fragment_title);
               case 1: return getString(R.string.other_fragment_title);
           }

           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use the new adapter:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Create your adapter and pass the support fragment manager
       MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

       // Set up the ViewPager with your pager adapter
       mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
       mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```